# FastAPI How to control fields in response based on user query parameter e.g fieldSet in FastAPI?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, fastapi

Hello All I am new to rest api and trying to write a get endpoint to which user send a query parameter say FieldSet. Based on values in FieldSet I want to return response.
For Example :
Endpoint : @app.get(/blogs/)
Blogs endpoint has say 100 fields. But user want to control which fields he/she may need in response.
User will hit URL as /blogs/?fieldSet=blogID,blogCreator.

So response only should contain two feilds.

Options

1. Is it possible with FastAPI's pyndantic response schema ? Can schema be created dynamically based on query parameter values ?
2. Should I create a a sql based on fieldSet values at runtime and create a response ?
3. if second option holds true , can we use SqlAlchemy or should I write raw SQLs against DB ?
4. Also, How to create nested json if one blog may have one or more creators ?

Comment: Define a schema that have all the possible fields as optional and only populate those that have values depending on the requested fields? Any nested schema will be handled automagically for you in the response, so 4) should be covered as long as you make sure to fetch the relevant data.

Comment: What do you mean “populate” only required ? I don’t want all fields in response.

Comment: You only set the values in the pydantic object that you want to return; i.e. those that you don't want to return you leave empty (with a None) value.